# IOS - Swift - Cannot assign to the result of this expression

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, expression, assign

I have a global variable :

```
var blockArray:Array2D<Block>
```

and in a function am trying to set one of the parts of the array with:

```
blockArray[block.column, block.row] = block
```

but I am getting the following error: "Cannot assign to the result of this expression". Usually this seems is to do with optionals, but my variable is not optional? I'm new to Swift.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for `Array2D`?

Comment: @ABakerSmith Code to initialise is: blockArray = Array2D<Block>(columns: NumColumns, rows: NumRows)

Comment: Most likely your Array2D cannot be modified with this subscript, maybe it's not marked as mutating or doesn't have a set method. We need to see the implementation to be able to help you

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/ygQVCYTNBBFjAxxMkBwLrm

Comment: @user2976601 No, this doesn't help at all, we need the implementation of `Array2D`

Comment: @Kametrixom Ah, sorry! I'd forgotten Array2D was a new class (I'm following a tutorial and Im quite far through!)  http://paste.ofcode.org/La3bXnfnsDuFv9waA4M2fK

Comment: Sorted it. Missed a setter from within the subscript method.      set(newValue){array[(row * columns) + column] = newValue}

Comment: @user2976601 yeah I thought so ;)